# Android 6.0 Permission Checks for reading TELEPHONE ACCESS

Tags: android

Is it possible to ask repeated prompt to the user,when the user provides deny in the permission(READ_PHONE_STATE) request pop up raised by shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale().
Once I Click on deny the prompt gets exited and my objective is to make him click only Allow.Is this achievable in android 6.0 Version ?

Answer (score 0):

No, if the user wants to Deny permission they will always have that option. Its up to the developer to deal with that situation.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` is just a *hint* for you, you can choose the ignore the method's return value, or choose not to call that method at all.

If you have a permission you must have for the app to function properly, you should pop a dialog explaining this in simple language to the user, and keep asking for the permission until (a) the user gives you the permission, or (b) the user decides to uninstall the app.